# Xcode React-Native: linker error - library not found for -lRCTTypeSafety after clean

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, xcode12

Xcode 12.3
Cocoapods 1.10.1
React Native CLI 4.13.1

I am having a recurring failure building a React Native app at the linking stage (`library not found for -lRCTTypeSafety`) in the Xcode "Archive" Build task. ("Product" > "Archive") It fails with the same error when I run the first "Build" after a "Clean Build Folder".

It does not occur when I run the "Build" task, which usually succeeds, but the "first build after a clean" behavior lines up with how the "Archive" task behaves, which appears to run an implicit "clean" first, so they appear to be a similar failure case.

None of the suggested remediations I've found on-line have worked. I am using the workspace, not the project file. FWIW, I have confirmed the same occurs using xcodebuild. (As opposed to the Xcode gui.) `xcodebuild clean build` fails reliably, as well as `xcodebuild archive`, but `xcodebuild build` succeeds if it isn't the first build after a `clean`.

Several Pod libraries are missing from the linker command when it fails. On a successful run, the `xcodebuild build` action has the following additional `-L` flags in the `clang` linking command that are missing on the failed attempts:

```
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/DoubleConversion
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FBReactNativeSpec
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Folly
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/RCTTypeSafety
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/RNCPicker
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-Core
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-CoreModules
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTAnimation
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTBlob
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTImage
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTLinking
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTNetwork
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTSettings
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTText
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTVibration
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-cxxreact
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-jsi
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-jsiexecutor
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-jsinspector
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/ReactCommon
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/<project>.app
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Yoga
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/glog
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/react-native-geolocation
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/react-native-maps
-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React-Core/AccessibilityResources.bundle
```

A successful `build` action has no `WriteAuxiliaryFile`, `CompileC`, or `Libtool` log lines, so it appears that the failed first attempt after a `clean` is actually building the Pod files correctly, just not providing the necessary paths to the linker command.

The `Libtool` lines for the missing library from a failed build look like:

```
Libtool /Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/RCTTypeSafety/libRCTTypeSafety.a normal (in target 'RCTTypeSafety' from project 'Pods')
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only arm64 -D -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk -L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/RCTTypeSafety -filelist /Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RCTTypeSafety.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RCTTypeSafety.LinkFileList -dependency_info /Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RCTTypeSafety.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RCTTypeSafety_libtool_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>-bcgmbzkfkmobskcxnhtpmhoehiux/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/RCTTypeSafety/libRCTTypeSafety.a
```

and I've checked that the output file `libRCTTypeSafety.a` is present in the path specified for the `-o` flag above. The directory that contains the file is included in the missing `-L` flags provided, so it *really* looks like there's just some step between compilation and linking that is getting missed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tried disabling parallel builds, no joy. So, this doesn't appear to be a race condition in build order or anything. (xcode's dependency management _should_ prevent that, anyway)

Comment: Making some progress now that I'm adding the path to the build product directories as a library search path, e.g. `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/RCTTypeSafety`. Setting "recursive" for just `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}` does not seem to be working.